# How do I install ATI drivers and keep them up-to-date?

Tags: installation, ati, updates, software-center

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit and my graphics card is ATI Radeon HD 7770.

So for example I want to install ATI Drivers, which I can simply find them on AMD Support page, which will give me the "AMD Catalyst™ 13.1 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver", fine I can download it though AMD page.

But there's some software that I can install from the Software Center (I actually, didn't check if AMD Catalyst was there, but I don't think…) Is the same to download and install the software from their original site other than downloading it though the Software Center?

If I install it though their site, will the program still auto-update when there's a new update for it?

Comment: Hello Blastcore, welcome on both Ubuntu and Ask Ubuntu ! Could you please edit your question to include your Ubuntu version (12.04 or 12.10) and your graphics card model ?

Comment: I've edited it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the most canonical method : open the Dash Menu, type "Software Sources", launch the "Software Sources" app, go to the Additional Drivers tab, follow the suggested instructions. This will install the driver that is tested and advised by the Ubuntu community (not necessarily the latest one).

As a very general rule, in Ubuntu you should prefer to install apps from a store rather than a developer-website or a download-website. Start with the Ubuntu Software Center. When you are familiar with it, come back to this page and you'll be able to try the following "stores", without any particular order : Launchpad PPAs, Steam, Desura, Humble Store, apt-get.

Comment: Might not be the good place to ask, but is Qt 5.0.1 on the Software Center (Which contains the Qt Creator IDE and the Qt 5.0.1 Libraries, sort of 700MB). I've looked for it but nothing, it's on the Qt site only.

Comment: No it is not the right to place but I'll answer anyway :-). If you install the Ubuntu Phone SDK you'll install Qt5 along. Refer to https://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/. If you have further questions, please open new ones.

Comment: So, i've done it. Just that i can't apply changes and it says Unknown on Driver. http://i.imgur.com/r9HOhAS.png

Comment: 2: So i've tried and there's difference between the Chrome in the Software Center, one is the name, second is that the one in the Center is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [how-to](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/install-ati-official-drivers-in-ubuntu/) to install the AMD proprietary drivers. Ignore the driver download part if you already did, and replace the name of the driver with the new one you have (the guide was written for 12.1 version)

Comment: Thanks, though. It's necessary to download all the stuff from the Software Center so it keeps up-to-date or downloading them though the official site will also do checks whenever there's an update?

Comment: Your catalyst will notify you if there is an update, and if you want to upgrade, you have to go through the entire process again